# asp.net mvc 4.5 using like or distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have this code

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 string myfname = item.fname.Substring(0, 1);     
 <option value="@myfname"> @myfname</option>
}
```

This selects the first letter of each fname in the database and I've got it to display in a drop down menu. If I have the names Max, John, Kris and Karen in the database it is displayed like this in the drop down,

- M
- J
- K
- K

notice how there is two K's, how can I change it so that it only displays 1 k in the drop down menu. So each letter is displayed only once. 
I think that this would be a LIKE statement but i'm not sure how to implement it.
Maybe something like, **Where fname LIKE...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this

```
@foreach (var letter in Model.Select(i => i.fname.Substring(0, 1)).Distinct()) {
    <option value="@letter">@letter</option>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(i => i.fname.Substring(0, 1).Distinct())
```